# MYSQL unique column

Tags: mysql

I have a large MySQL table with data which has been duplicated for 1 column.

I want to further limit duplicate entry but don't want to mess with the existing data.

I know there is a UNIQUE option for MYSQL column which can be applied but it wont work on existing data.

I know I can cleanup the data and then apply it but I am trying not to do that because of sensitivity of the data.

Is there any other way to make the MYSQL column unique?

Thanks.

```
ALTER TABLE `testtable`.`parcel` 
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `licence_plate_UNIQUE` (`licence_plate` ASC);
```

Error:

```
Executing:
ALTER TABLE `testtable`.`parcel` 
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `licence_plate_UNIQUE` (`licence_plate` ASC);

Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
ERROR 1062: Duplicate entry '00004158697' for key 'licence_plate_UNIQUE'
SQL Statement:
ALTER TABLE `testtable`.`parcel` 
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `licence_plate_UNIQUE` (`licence_plate` ASC)
```

Comment: if you add an index t oexisting data and the current data would break that index, you get an error - that is what is happening here

Comment: `select * from testtable.parcel where licence_plate_UNIQUE = '00004158697'` will give you more than one result

Comment: yes but doing this check before insertion on a big table will slow down user experience

Comment: If you can't clean up the data it sounds like the design of your database is wrong. Licence plates are unique in the real world so why are you storing them in a way which allows duplicates? Without knowing the existing table structure and a better description of what you are trying to achieve it's hard to give a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer**

Fix your data, get rid of the duplicates and apply the unique index. Any other solution is going to be a horrible hack

**Horrible Hack Answer**

Create another table with single field `licence_plate` as the primary key (which will enforce uniqueness) and then copy your data to it using a `distinct` select.

When you need to perform an insert you would have to try to insert in to this new table first, if it fails you have a duplicate. If not, go ahead and insert in to the main table.

Comment: If you are doing it this way, you could just use the `create table as select distinct ...`

Comment: @JoSSte - Yes, and doing it that way could be faster because you would apply the primary key index after the table had been loaded with data.